# Фильтр на React

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, filter

В `state` массив и функция:

```js
prices: [
    {price: 1030},
    {price: 500},
    {price: 15500},
    {price: 1300},
    {price: 900},
]
```

Записываю его так:

```
filterino = () => {
    let currentPrices = store._state.airCard.prices.filter(function (item) {
        return item.price > 1000;}
    );
```

По идее, в переменной `currentPrices` копия с 3 объектами.

Вопрос, как мне отрисовать `currentPrices` не перезатирая текущий `state`? Или всегда актуальный `state` будет запрашиваться с сервера перед вызовом фильтра и все ок?

Comment: В `render()` использовать значения, которые вернет `filterino()`. Если значения в `state` поменяются, то компонент заново вызовет `render()` и `filterino()` вернет новые значения на основе `state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если перед вызовом метода фильтрации всегда запрашивается список `prices`, и после получения данных применяется фильтр ([`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)), то отрисовка `currentPrices`, содержащее отфильрованный новый массив со всеми элементами, прошедшими проверку, должна отработать нормально (как минимум потому что `filter` возвращает новый массив не пораждает мутации). Просто для рендеринга используйте полученную копию `currentPrices` из `filterino` метода.

Однако такой подход, вероятно, отправляет лишние запросы на сервер для получения данных. 
Если данные, получаемые для `prices`, на стороне сервера изменяются не часто - рекомендую посмотреть в сторону хранения аргуметов фильтрации в параметрах URL к примеру, либо храните применяемые фильтры в `state` компонента и перед рендерингом получайте отфильрованный массив и затем рендерите его. Чтобы снизить количество запросов к серверу.